# Automatically convert smart quotes into regular quotes

Tags: feature-request

I keep seeing a bunch of questions with code that use smart quotes instead of regular quotes, which not only messes up syntax highlighting but doesn't run properly either. For example:

```js
console.log(“Smart quotes.”)
```

Compared to:

```js
console.log("Smart quotes.")
```

For those unfamiliar with smart quotes, look closely and notice that they are slightly slanted. I suspect that they are a result of people writing questions/answers from their smartphones

These are really annoying and have no benefit ever. Can we automatically convert all smart quotes in new posts into regular quotes?

Comment: The problem with automatically changing these is that they might actually be the cause of the issue. Better to ask OP to check and edit the post

Comment: What will happen to questions who legitimately use `”` in their code? People might want to ask something like "How to automatically replace `”` with `"`....

Comment: I have seen several questions with code taken from a website that didn't set a proper stylesheet for code (the stylesheet changed the quotes) and that was the cause of the problem (or at least a clear symptom that the OP didn't really know what they were doing).

Comment: Maybe... if it is part of a warning only. "The content contains smart quotes. Click <here> to replace them with regular quotes". Then it is the author's fault if the swap mucks up their question/answer. BTW: posts like this are more convincing if you can back up the "bunch" claim with some links to (recent) questions that portray the issue. It is not like anyone has a reason to not believe you, except for the fact that some people do like to wave with their arms a lot and call 2 occurrences a week "a lot".

Comment: Re *"a result of people writing questions/answers from their smartphones"*: Or copying code from a web page, say a blog post. Or copying code through chat at work, say Skype chat. It is a very common source of error, and needs to be covered on Stack Overflow. It should be possible to google for cryptic errors like ***"Â : The term 'Â' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"*** and immediately find the solution (and preventive detection/measures). Though there ought to be only a very small number of canonical questions for them.

Comment: cont' - But with the massive duplication on Stack Overflow, it is spread over [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12111606), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14159491), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18866318), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19198332), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20420890), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20860601), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2340930), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24101120), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33310174), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33562102), ...

Comment: cont' - [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3442858), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38343182), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42536924), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43268151), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46303148), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47434802), [lots and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7663565) of duplicates!

Comment: [Skype reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663565/error-stray-xxx-in-c-program-why-does-this-happen#comment117570515_7663565). It was caused by [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x) and can be searched (and replaced) for in, e.g., modern text editors by the regular expression `\x{00A0}`.

Comment: @PeterMortensen SO does have lots of duplication, but in this specific instance I'd say the blame is fully on copy/paste coding :) A widespread practice leads to widespread confusion.

Comment: There are so many ways people can make a snippet non-reproducible. Instead of anticipating and fixing some of the common lost-in-translation issues with probably disastrous/unanticipated side effects, it's better to educate askers so they know they need to run the code they post to verify it reproduces the exact problem/error they're asking about.

Answer (score 9):

> Can we automatically convert all smart quotes in new posts into regular quotes?

Before:

```js
console.log("what if I want “Smart quotes.” in my code?");
```

After this proposal is implemented:

```js
console.log("what if I want "Smart quotes." in my code?");
```